# Bad API key for Maps - does it depend on google account

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a question about maps API key.
I'm writing an Android app which uses Google Maps. When I run app in debug mode it shows me nothing but that gray grid. I know it's about bad API key since I've read dozen of questions on this site. I've tried a lot of time to get valid API key. When that didn't work I've deleted debug.keystore file and Eclipse generated me a new one and than with that new keystore I've got new API key. Still it didn't work. Than I've tried Eclipse plugin Keytool. Same result (nothing shown but the grid). 
Since I am in a firm, we have proxy so I've tried with and without proxy settings on emulator (2.3.3 with Google API's). And that didn't work.
I've tried againt to gain API key but I've accidentally loged in with different Google account and Google gave me different API key for the same MD5 fingerprint.
So my question is am I using bad Google account since I am in a firm (what account should I use) and if so how can I make correct account with which I would get API key that will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial explains the steps you need to take: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

In particular, the important point is to ensure that your developer signing keys match the Maps API key. So if you use your personal signing key for your Android app, you'll need to use a Maps API key for that. If you use the company signing key, you'll need to use a different Maps API key.

The exact steps you need to get the Maps API key are described at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey, but I would start off with the tutorial, and when it's working, you will now that the whole chain is good, and can then return to your own code.

Comment: I've retrieved company's signing key but it still doesn't work. I've read tutirial multiple times and I can't see why it still doesn't work.